# How to set correct country?

Tags: windows-8, wordament

I'm playing [Wordament](http://www.wordament.com/) on my Windows 8 laptop as a Windows app and I log in using an Xbox account (I created it only for this purpose with Microsoft account). The country which is displayed in game is Romania (wrong), though I never set it up like that. On the Xbox billing information, the country is correct, on the Microsoft account also. Couldn't find any information about this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the options in the game and then drag up on the options, you should see an option to change your location flag.  From there, you just select the correct country.